# Can we do a better job of providing useful feedback?

Tags: discussion, moderation

My Flag Message:

> This answer, while highly rated, offers up outdated information. It should be edited at a minimum to prevent users from applying this code in new projects.

Mod:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

So then **WHAT SHOULD I DO?**

Comment: What is the moderator supposed to do that you can't?  If you think something is wrong with the answer, comment on it, suggest an edit, or post your own answer to solve the problem.

Comment: You're supposed to 1) comment on the answer asking the OP to update it (or mark it community wiki so that you can edit it) 2) post your own answer with up to date information.

Comment: I don't know, clean up the answer?  I'm capable, sure, but I'm not attempting to be a mod.  Just giving a heads-up that "hey, this is probably not great to have here"

Comment: Can you not just edit the question with up to date information? If you are able to interpret it as outdated, I assume you know of a way in which to currently make the same logic functional

Comment: @Funktr0n Moderators are human exception handlers meaning they step in where the rest of the community can't.  Suggesting an edit, commenting, or posting another answer is something **you can do**, a moderator isn't needed for that.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier Suggesting an edit that changes an answer could get rejected as conflicting with the author's intent and/or an attempt to reply.

Comment: @bluefeet ok, well whatever.  The flag rejection answer wasn't helpful.  Probably should be better.  I'll let you guys do whatever you feel like you should do

Comment: Better how? It did tell you that you shouldn't flag answers for technical issues. What do you want it to tell you?

Comment: I would suggest that the answer is **never** edited or removed, while it may be outdated for some people, others may rely on outdated functionality when dealing with legacy systems or lower specced/older machines. These answers are invaluable to them! Instead you should be submitting *your own* answer to include up to date information.

Answer (score 6):

Um. You kinda noted what you should do *in your flag*:

> It should be edited at a minimum to prevent users from applying this code in new projects.

**You can do that.** Suggest an edit. Be respectful of the original author & explain why you're editing in the revision notes. You don't need a moderator to do it for you (and indeed, chances of a random moderator knowing what should be edited are slim).

Comment: Isn't it pretty evident by my using the Flag feature that I'm thinking it works differently?  The flag answer wasn't helpful toward getting a resolution on the problem, it just basically said that I was using flags wrong.  I get you guys probably feel attacked here, but if you can see that my flag is generally in the vein of trying to get something positive accomplished, you can do better than just dismissing the attempt.  All you're doing is disincentivizing me to participate

Comment: I don't feel particularly attacked, I just don't see where we could do better here; what would you have expected in a response that would've pointed you in the right direction?

Comment: Something like, "got it, thanks.  I'm dismissing your flag because they aren't intended to be used for that purpose, but if you feel confident enough in a proposed edit, you should use the 'Suggest an edit' feature on the answer with a note about the situation"

Comment: Maybe propose that then...?

Comment: I don't even know how to do that.  I'm the guy who misused Flags.

Comment: You post a question like this one, but instead of titling it "what should I do" you title it "I think mods should do..." and maybe tag it [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: all right, I did it.  heading out now, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use flags for actions that can be done by community.

You should:

- provide feedback on the answer (downvote, comment)
- consider editing answer if change is relatively minor or obvious (drastic edits are not welcome and essentially not possible without full edit privileges)
- provide new high quality answer that demonstrates new and improved solution
- vote to close if you know better duplicate

Comment: Thanks for at least addressing the unknown.  I do appreciate that.

Answer (score -4):

Apparently no.  According to the comment thread, Moderators are human exception handlers, nothing more.

Comment: Y'know, awkwardly, it doesn't seem like this answer "No" answers the question "what should I do?" ;)

Comment: @jimsug ya know, awkwardly, someone edited my initial question.  Great comment though.

Comment: @Funktr0n, the question's title may have been edited, but the body concludes with "**WHAT SHOULD I DO?**". This was present in the original version, including the bold and all caps, and has not been edited. So the comment, though a bit snarky, is not entirely without merit.