# In cases where users are misusing Flags I think mods should both explain the dismissal and propose a preferred action

Tags: feature-request

In a previous Question, I spoke of a situation where I hadn't found the Flag dismissal message to be particularly helpful.  The initial Flag message had read:

> This answer, while highly rated, offers up outdated information. It should be edited at a minimum to prevent users from applying this code in new projects.

The Mod response was

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I think something like...

> got it, thanks. I'm dismissing your flag because they aren't intended to be used for that purpose, but if you feel confident enough in a proposed edit, you should use the "Suggest an edit" feature on the answer with a note about the situation

would have been far more helpful.  I didn't have any idea what the proper course of action was.

Comment: The mods don't really have the time to write custom explanations... There are just too many flags to handle.

Comment: The response is clear and concise. Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer. If you need more information than that, check the help center and meta. If you haven't found the information you were looking for after that, post a meta question.

Comment: @TinyGiant You guys (the larger moderator collective) here at SO have had the same motto for years: you're never wrong.  Well, whatever man, I'm bold-faced telling you that your current method is unclear, and it undeniably is, but if you want to pretend that it isn't, fine.  Good luck with that, I won't bother again.

Comment: I just stated my position. Everyone is free to agree or disagree with that position as they see fit... and believe you me, I've had my fair share of people disagree with me 'round these parts.

Comment: Keep in mind, I am a moderator in that everyone on this site is a moderator, but only diamond moderators (those with diamonds after their names, elected by the community) decline flags. Diamond moderators are few and far between, and the number of flags they have to process in a day is rather large. Personalized decline messages dont scale.

Comment: @TinyGiant  Being short on manpower is at least a reasonable explanation for why this can't be implemented, and one I'd wholly accept.  What I don't like is this oft-seen defensiveness where everything gets justified by refusing to acknowledge the problem

Comment: I don't personally see the lack of personalized decline messages as a problem.

Comment: @TinyGiant Well, I guess if you don't think user confusion and frustration is an issue (the resultant effect of reading a terse dismissal message after attempting to do something helpful), then you're right -- nothing to discuss.

Comment: I do view user confusion and frustration as an issue. In fact I am a huge proponent of user education initiatives. I think that there are plenty of issues with the UI that in turn cause poor UX, but I don't view the lack of personalized decline messages as one of those things. If you get a declined flag and you can't figure out why it was declined, come to meta and ask.

Comment: We may seem harsh at times, but most of us are real people. I suggest reading [Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/4639281) as well.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm literally telling you that the lack of information in the dismissal message was the direct cause of my frustration and yet you're not convinced.  I agree that there are other ways to solve the problem (make the flag button's purpose more descriptive when you use it, completely destroy the Internet, etc.) but now you're just changing the target for the sake of argument.  There's a problem here somewhere, and it should be acknowledged.  The dismissal message in its current form is unhelpful toward problem resolution.  I think that's pretty obvious.

Comment: @TinyGiant I read the thread you linked to and I agree.  That kind of behavior has prevailed on SO and its affiliates for as long as I can remember and that's what I was talking about earlier.  You can see it even on my initial post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351191/can-we-do-a-better-job-of-providing-useful-feedback/351193#351193.  I get snarky comments about how my answer didn't answer my question (despite my question being edited), and my answer literally came from the comment thread itself.  It's mob mentality, it's juvenile, and it's ridiculous.

Comment: The flag decline message was _not_ the direct cause of your confusion. The cause of your confusion is the deficiencies in the UI that cause you to think that you're doing the right thing when you are in fact not. The decline message was factual and accurate. Note that [searching for that exact phrase using google is extremely helpful](https://www.google.com/search?q=Flags+should+not+be+used+to+indicate+technical+inaccuracies%2C+or+an+altogether+wrong+answer), the same as if you were searching for an error message.

Comment: You can't just yell "mob mentality" any time you have an unpopular thought, it's lazy. Instead try to take some time and understand _why_ the majority disagree with you.

Comment: "It should be edited at minimum" - You think that the moderator that viewed your flag would really know *why* and *how* it was outdated? Moderators don't know every programming language on earth! You should have added a new answer.

Comment: I maintain that this was not a case where [suggesting an edit to the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/4076315) was appropriate.

Comment: @TinyGiant No, the message really _was_ the direct cause of my frustration here.  Since the message is so terse and non-descriptive toward problem resolution, it communicates the notion that a Human moderator actually ready my message, saw that I was trying to be helpful, and didn't care whatsoever.  He/she then thought it appropriate to send me a message that completely disregarded my attempt at being helpful, and gave no further instruction.  Not everyone will agree with me when I say that that's rude, but it's unhelpful at best, and that's probably something to improve.

Comment: @paper1111 Hence my suggested alternative.  I don't expect the mods to know anything more than what I _should_ do as an alternative to using the Flag tool.  And if they know that, it would be helpful for them to communicate said action.

Comment: @Funktr0n If the system hadn't made you think that what you were doing was helping, then you wouldn't have done that thing, and you wouldn't have had your flag declined. You were confused because the system made you think that you were being helpful. You can refuse to acknowledge this as much as you want, but repeating yourself isn't going to change my opinion on the matter. It is impossible with a site of this scale to include what the flagger should have done instead in each and every decline message.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not necessarily against the general idea but I think Tiny Giant has a point with:

> The cause of your confusion is the deficiencies in the UI that cause
>   you to think that you're doing the right thing when you are in fact
>   not.

The only reason you flagged the answer in the first place was because you thought it needed moderator attention. Why? Is there a reason you felt normal user actions (comments, voting) wouldn't work here? If there's something on the site that says/implies that moderators should be handling answers that are wrong or outdated then *that's* what needs to be fixed.

If the message were to change, a smaller change to the automatic flag message would be better:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Even better would be a link in the dialog where users choose a flag to use:

> A problem not listed above that [requires action by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). *Be
>   specific and detailed!*

The links above go to the help page but pretend they go to a FAQ or other Meta post that's more specific about the correct use of the flag, possibly covering common misuses of the flag.

All that said, I don't expect there to be a change unless bad moderator flags are a thing that happens a lot.

Comment: I think the links are a step in the right direction.  In response to the deficiencies in the UI being the cause of my frustration, I responded to TG above.